# Solution to maintain an active button with CSS in a new section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm beginner in javascript and i need help to resolve a problem i have in my test website. 
I need a top menu with a active button when i click on them.
For this example i only need the active css class for button 1 and 2. The button 3 is a link to a mailto: and the button 4 is a logout.

[active button when selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlQax.png)

I found one solution for the active class button, but i won a new problem.

HTML:

```
<menu id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-tachometer fa-lg"></i><p class="desc_menu">BTN_1</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?nav=1" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-cogs fa-lg"></i><p class="desc_menu">BTN_2</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="mailto:xpto@xpto.com" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-lg">EMAIL</i><p class="desc_menu">COMUNICATIONS</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="exit.php" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-rocket fa-lg"></i><p class="desc_menu">EXIT</p></a></li>
    </ul>
</menu>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function() {
    var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
    .lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    $("#nav ul li a").each(function(){
      if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
        $(this).addClass("activ");
      })
  });
```

When i click in the green section link, the active css button on the top menu disappear. I need the button remaining active.

[active button disappear when i click the green section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyG9j.png)

How i can resolve this problem? Any opinion?

Thank's

Comment: Please add the HTML of the sections and the click-handler Javascript to the question.

Comment: What does the green section actually do when you click it? Does it reload the page with  a different url - in which case then maybe it no longer matches. Also - rather than using lastIndexOf it might be easier to use the location object to pull out the part of the url you want to match: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location - perhaps location.pathname? I suspect you are failing to match because you are using a mix of pathnames and query strings. being clear about this might help.

Comment: The green sections are php pages that have html and php code. I put these pages in index.php with the php include function. 
It has a link that directs us to another page (also included in index.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use different classes for the two sections,
i.e:

```
$("#nav ul li a.btn-default").each(function(){
     //ignore if button type is green, assuming you have a specific identifier for this type of button
     if($(this).hasClass('green')) //Lets say your green button has a particula class or identifier
        return; //Do nothing when green button clicked

     //Else add the active class
     if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
        $(this).addClass("activ");
})
```

And your green buttons for this example to work should have a class called 'green'. You can use anything of-course.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `location.pathname` and `location.search`:

```
$(function() {
    var pgurl;
        pgurl = location.search == '' 
                ? window.location.pathname.slice(1) 
                : location.pathname.split('?')[0];

    $('#nav a[href="'+pgurl+'"]').addClass('activ');
});
```

As i can see you have different navigation process with blue ones and green ones. With blue ones you can get the current navigated page with `location.pathname` and if you navigate with green buttons then you should use `location.search` as above in the answer.

Comment: Yes, I have two different navigations. The blue section are the main navigation buttons and the green areas are images with links to another page . When I enter the page BTN_1 the button is active by default. When I click the button BTN_2 this goes to active. If I click on the image that is in the green area , I need to change to another page and keep active BTN_2 button.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script

```
 $(function() {
    $('#nav ul').find('a[href="' + location.pathname + location.search + '"]').addClass('active');
  });
```

Also your script seems to be fine, Except one small typo error.

`$(this).addClass("activ");` should be `$(this).addClass("active");` .  You have typed as `activ`